# Flutter and Amplify Authenticator

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, flutter-aws-amplify

I'm new to Flutter and AWS amplify so this may be basic but looking for help.

I am creating a test mobile application with flutter. In the application, the user will be able to journal (like a diary). This information will be stored in a database (most probably AWS RDS)

I wanted to know, after I connect flutter with amplify authenticator, how exactly will the user that is in AWS cognito be connected to their application specific information stored in another database?

I'm not able to find any information on this.

I tried looking online for this type of scenario and wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Cognito instance via Amplify CLI, IAM roles are created automatically.

IAM roles define which resources can be accessed by a user. You can inspect them after `amplify add auth` in your aws console in IAM section.

If you login to your app, cognito gives you a set of credentials (AccessKeyId, SecretKey, SessionToken). On every subsequent request, AccessKeyId and Secret Key are used to [sign the request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) and the SessionToken is attached as X-Amz-Security-Token in the request header.

On the server side Cognito and other AWS Services can determine which role is associated with your SessionToken and therefore, check which resources you are allowed to access.

I would recommend that you do not use RDS (Aurora?) and use DynamoDB instead.

With Aurora you have to pay from the beginning even if you have not traffic and it is very painful to integrate into an amplify project compared to DynamoDB. You also have to take care of appropriate IAM roles etc. yourself.

With DynamoDB everything is baked into Amplify and everything is setup automatically in minutes.